# Remote Raspberry Pi 3D graphic using VirtualGL/TurboVNC?

Tags: raspbian

Is it possibile to use [VirtualGL/TurboVNC](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2986/is-it-possible-to-access-a-gpu-remotely-i-e-from-another-machine) on Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well someone would have to change the source code of VirtualGL/TurboVNC to use the Raspberry Pi's GPU. There are some projects floating around on the Raspberry Pi [Forums](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/). Currently it's not possible, unless someone changes the source code.

**Normal VNC use** If you just want to use normal VNC, as suggested in the first comment, then you can just use [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/). Here is a guide on how to get [TightVNC working on a Raspberry Pi](http://elinux.org/RPi_VNC_Server), do note though that you will not be able to use VNC to see anything being rendered by the GPU IE: Video playback, GPU games (Quake 3, PenguinPuzzle). Just thought I might add this section based on the first comment.

Comment: I don't think this is what Ebrahim is asking at all. Presumably, Ebrahim would like to use Raspberry Pi as a thin client that connects to a more powerful machine using VNC. Typically VNC works with X by drawing 2D information and forwarding openGL calls to the client. While Raspberry Pi can handle some openGL 3d, any server with a discrete video card will likely out perform it. TurboVNC keeps openGL calls on the VNC server and renders them there, before JPEG compressing them and sending them over the network. This means less powerful machines can run more powerful 3d instructions lossily.

Comment: @DavidJFelix. Valid point. I've edited my answer, I assumed that the asker was specifically asking about forwarding the GPU output over VNC.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can run thinlinc on the host, which includes virtualgl. On the pi, you can use the html5 browser epiphany as your viewer. The speeds won't be great though.

Answer (score 1):

Like the post above mine I too needed to remotely view a Kivy application that was running on a Raspberry Pi. I wanted to use the existing Jessie installation, however, and not install KivyPie. I eventually managed to do it using dispmanx_vncserver on the Pi and connecting to it with TurboVNC from a Mac.

The installation of dispmanx_vncserver can be found here:
http://raspmer.blogspot.com.es/2015/07/vnc-server-for-raspberry-pi-with.html
What I had to do was enter the following commands on the Pi

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.7 g++-4.7 libvncserver-dev
git clone https://github.com/Na1w/dispmanx_vnc.git
```

cd into the dispmanx_vnc directory and

```
make
```

then to start the server type

```
sudo ./dispmanx_vncserver
```

and I connected from my Mac using TurboVNC.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will be useful at all, but thought i'd share.

I needed a remote viewer to view and control a Kivy application which is built off openGL ES. In the regular Jessie, environment this proved very difficult to achieve. You have to use dispmanx and build some sort vnc server and forward framebuffers etc. However, Kivypie OS has this feature integrated and already prebuilt. I'm not sure on its limitations to other libraries available or what can or can't be installed, but with this I was able to successfully view a 3d kivy application via ultravnc from the open gl es. Kivypie seems to be a barebones OS retrofitted for a kivy environment, but I am still new to it and have yet to test its flexibility.

If you go the kivypie route, here's some tips:

user / pass = sysops / posys

This will start the dispman vncserver which is is probably viewable from a number of vnc clients. In my case I used UltraVNC.

```
sudo dispman_vncserver
```

Hope this helps.